# Adam in Tensorflow: where does moment estimates happen?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization, tensor

I know that optimizers in Tensorflow divide `minimize` into `compute_gradients` and `apply_gradients`. However, optimization algorithms like Adam generally process the gradients with momentum and some other techniques as the following figure suggests(Thanks @kmario23 for providing the figure).
[image]
I wonder when these techniques are applied to the gradients? Are they applied in `compute_gradients` or `apply_gradients`?

### Update

```
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y = tf.layers.dense(x, 1)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(tf.ones_like(y), y)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(grads, feed_dict={x: [[1]]}))
print(sess.run(grads, feed_dict={x: [[1]]}))
```

The above code outputs the same results twice, does it suggest that moment estimates are computed in `apply_gradients`? Because, IMHO, if moment estimates are computed in `apply_gradients`, then after the first `print` statement, first and second moments will be updated, which should result in different result in the second `print`statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compute_gradients` computes only gradients, all other additional operations corresponding to specific optimization algorithms are done in `apply_gradients`. The code in the update is one evidence, another evidence is the following figure cropped from tensorboard, where Adam corresponds to the `compute_gradient` operation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Below is the Adam algorithm as presented in the Deep Learning book. As for your question, the important thing to note here is the *gradient of theta* (written as Laplacian of theta) in second to last step.

[image: adam]

As for how TensorFlow computes this is a [two step process in the optimization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients) (i.e. *minimization*)

- 1) [`compute_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#compute_gradients)
- 2) [`apply_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#apply_gradients)

In the first step all the necessary ingredients for the final gradients are computed. So, the second step is just applying the update to the parameters based on the gradients computed in the first step and the learning rate (`lr`).

Comment: Hi, I've tested your answer by running `compute_gradients` twice and checking their output gradients. Both output the same results. If moment estimates in your figure are updated in the `compute_gradients`, then `hat s` and `hat r` should be updated after the first call, which, IMHO, should result in different `Delta theta` in the second call. Why would two gradients still be the same?